# Passing parameters in MultiJob Project Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I try to pass parameter about maven profile in multijob project but unfortunately Jenkins doesn`t see it and execute: 'mvn clean install $PROFILE'. Do you know any solution?

[image: MultiJob Project]

[image: SubBuild View]

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a maven command as  `clean install -Dprofile=dev`
Here "profile" is the parameter and "dev" is its value.